# Using an eventlistener instead of onclick

Tags: javascript

I have a ul that when each li is clicked, the text in its nested span gets sent to an input. I was advised to replace my (many) onclicks- one on each li in the list with an eventlistener on the ul. could use advice on how to do this neatly with same functionality.

html:

```
<ul>
<li  onclick="myfunction(this)"><img src="img1"><span>Some text</span></li>
<li  onclick="myfunction(this)"><img src="img2"><span>Some other text</span></li>          
</ul>
<input id="field_jd6brw">
```

Javascript:

```
function myfunction(li){
document.getElementById("field_jd6brw").value = li.childNodes[1].textContent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to stick to plain-vanilla JavaScript, you can use something like this:

```
function myfunction(){
    document.getElementById("field_jd6brw").value = this.children[1].innerHTML;
}    

var aLi = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');

for (var i=0, len = aLi.length; i<len; i++) {
    aLi[i].addEventListener('click', myfunction, false);
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Tm5/**

This code selects all LI within a UL (use more specific selectors, like ID of UL if needed) and then loops thru each LI element adding the event listener.

Note that this code won't work in old versions of IE - you either need to add IE-specific code or switch to jQuery

Answer (score 3):

simply use jquery :

```
$("ul li").click(function (){

    $("#field_jd6brw").val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: You're using jQuery already, no need for `document.getElementById`